# Share variable state between ViewModels in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I created an application with a topbar (HeaderViewModel) and a link on it that opens a modal with a login form (LoginViewModel).

**The LoginViewModel assigned to the modal handles the login functionality:**

```
var LoginViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();

    self.loggedIn = ko.observable(false);

    self.login = function () {
        // loggedIn true if ajax succeeded
    }
    ...
}
```

After the login (ajax call) has succeeded the modal closes and the HeaderViewModel should be aware of the loggedIn state so the knockout if/else statement can handle the visibilities according the the users role.

**#header (only attached to HeaderViewModel)**:

```
<!-- ko if: loggedIn --> //loggedIn not known in HeaderViewModel
    <p>Visible for logged in users</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**app.js:**

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new HeaderViewModel, $("#header")[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel, $("#login")[0]);
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different approaches.

## 1. Root view model

Don't call `ko.applyBindings` twice. Instead, create one Root view model that composes the other two.

```
function RootViewModel() {
    this.headerViewModel = new HeaderViewModel();
    this.loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```html
<body>
  <div data-bind="with: headerViewModel">
  </div>
  <div data-bind="with: loginViewModel">
    login dialog code here
  </div>
  etc.
</body>
```

You can then choose any javascript method of your liking to make sure the `login` feature will share its knowledge, including:

- Calling `$root.login` in the login `div` and placing login code there;
- `new`ing the `LoginViewModel` with a parameter: a callback to notify the `$root` and possibly other sub view models (like the `Header`) of changed current user credentials;

## 2. Pub-sub

Use some kind of pub-sub mechanism. Options include:

- [Tiny PubSub](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub)
- [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

The `LoginViewModel` will publish login results, and any subscriber can respond accordingly.

Comment: I tried both solutions but went for the Knockout-postbox one because it feels very easy to use. Thanks!